# Adding Subview affect on Move animation - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

I am trying to make a simple application where there are 3 balloon buttons. When user clicks any of the button, they are animated(moved) to their new positions! All this works from this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
   //Moving the Sum (Button)
     CGRect frame =  Sum.frame;
     frame.origin.y = -20;
     frame.origin.x = (-120);
     Sum.frame = frame;
     .....
....




 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     NSLog(@"Completed");
    //adding subview
    [self.view addSubview:newView];

 }];
```

But if i try to add subviews to the self.view!Why do all buttons come back to their respective positions before move animation! is this my default? or i am doing something wrong? i want to counter this behaviour?!  Please Help!

Comment: You want that animation to be done after adding subview?

Comment: before addSubview!.. i have written the code too, after move animation is completed.. add the subview!